# OSX: Is it possible to have the task switcher (cmd + tab) show on all monitors, but only show the apps specific to each monitor?

Tags: macos

I currently have my settings such that the task switcher appears on all monitors (I have 3).  But it shows ALL open apps on each monitor.

Is there any way to have each one only show the open apps that have windows on each individual monitor?

In other words, if I have chrome open on Monitor 2, but not Monitors 1 or 3, is there a way that the task switcher that shows on Monitor 2 will show Chrome, but it won't appear on the task switcher that appears on Monitors 2 and 3?

I'm currently on Ventura (13.3.1).

Comment: In short, no. . . [This has been asked many times before, but the search terms fine enough to pinpoint it…. My google-fu fails me ;) btw, it hasn't been called OS X since 2015, it's macOS. It was never OSX.